# Outlet doesn't show up in Interface Builder (Xcode 3) nor Xcode4

Tags: iphone, ios4, iboutlet, outlet

I'm learning to develop iOS apps (I am a total newbie in Objective-C and Cocoa), and I am doing this really simple example exercise (two buttons that shows Left or Right button is pressed in a Label).

I just create an IBOutlet and a couple of code lines, save both AppViewController files and when trying to connect the IBOutlet with the actual label in the Interface Builder, the outlet doesn't show up.

I'm using the iOS SDK 4.3

Here's the source code:

```
//
//  BotonViewController.h
//  Boton
//
//  Created by Abu on 5/23/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Hola_MundoViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *statusText; 

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *statusText;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender;

@end
```

And

```
//
//  BotonViewController.m
//  Boton
//
//  Created by Abu on 5/23/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BotonViewController.h"

@implementation Hola_MundoViewController
@synthesize statusText;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender
{
NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                     @"%@ button pressed.", title];
statusText.text = newText;
[newText release];
}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:         (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[statusText release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Well, that's it, hope you can help me with this, probably is a silly mistake, but I've browsed a lot and I cannot find a solution.

Comment: @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusText;

Comment: Have you checked whether the FilesOwner Property is set correctly? To do so, open your ViewController in Xcode4's interface builder, select Files's Owner on the left side and go the the third tab (Identity Inspector) on the right side. Class shout be Hola_MundoViewController

Comment: Looks like the missing IBOutlet was responsible for that (that happens when you use old documentation to learn xD), thanks for that, TheBlack.

Comment: @TheBlack:  Please post it as an answer so the OP can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property declaration should look like this

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusText;
```